# How can I create an array of member function pointers coupled with different objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Say I have class `A` with function `foo(int i)` and class `B` with function `bar(int i)`, as well as `objectA` (of class `A`) and `objectB` (of class `B`). I can call the functions like so

```
objectA.foo(10);
objectB.bar(20);
```

What I would like to do is have them both as function pointers in an array `arr` and calling them like so

```
arr[0](10);
arr[1](20);
```

Is there a way of doing this in C++? If so, how efficient is it?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Sorry, forgot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store `std::function` objects in a `std::vector` that you create from lambda functions capturing `objectA` or `objectB`. Calling `std::function` objects comes with a little overhead so if time is critical, you'll have to measure if it's good enough.

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    void foo(int x) { std::cout << "A::foo " << x << '\n'; }
};

struct B {
    void bar(int x) { std::cout << "B::bar " << x << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    A objectA;
    B objectB;
    std::vector< std::function<void(int)> > arr{
        [&objectA](int x) { objectA.foo(x); },
        [&objectB](int x) { objectB.bar(x); },
    };
    arr[0](10);
    arr[1](20);
}
```

Output:

```
A::foo 10
B::bar 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to **@ted-lyngmo**'s answer, but with C++20, you can also use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) to create the function object for the vector:

```cpp
int main()
{
    A objectA;
    B objectB;
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> arr{
        std::bind_front(&A::foo, objectA),
        std::bind_front(&B::bar, objectB)
    };
    arr[0](10);
    arr[1](20);
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EnGEWP6rY)

Comment: Though this will copy objects of type `A` and `B` - could be a good thing if you need the closure functions to live longer than `objectA` and `objectB`, or bad if you need the calls to use the original objects. To tell it not to copy, we could do `std::bind_front(&A::foo, std::ref(objectA)), std::bind_front(&B::bar, std::ref(objectB))`